# Interpolating a data series of longitude and latitude coordinates - Error in input data

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I would like to perform a interpolation based on a set of Longitude and Latitude values.

I tried this with the library SciPy.interpolate. The code shown below also works without problems on simple data series.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
import csv

csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(file=file_path))
longitude = []
latitude = []
for row in csv_file:
    longitude.append(float(row['longitude']))
    latitude.append(float(row['latitude']))

plt.scatter(longitude, latitude, color='blue', label='given')

tck, u = interpolate.splprep([longitude, latitude], s=0.0)
x_i, y_i= interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 100), tck)

plt.plot(x_i, y_i, color='green', label='calculated')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

If I try to execute the code with real longitude and latitude values, I get an exception whose meaning I cannot interpret.

The exception is thrown in the 15 line:
`(tck, u = interpolate.splprep([longitude, latitude], s=0.0))`

It says: `ValueError: Invalid inputs.`
But I just don't know which inputs should be invalid. All values that were read in are float values, None values are also not present. The interpolation should be executed on about 900 coordinates. But even with 50 coordinates this exception is thrown. Are there any limitations in my code that could explain such an exception?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a had some duplicate data in my dataset. Obviously scipy has some problems with dealing with it.
As a removed all duplicate data points the code shown above worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

There must be an issue with the csv import, I just ran your code as is with 1000 random float pairs and it executed without any errors.
Try initializing your arrays with

```py
for i in range(0, 1000):
    longitude.append(random.randrange(0.0, 120.0))
    latitude.append(random.randrange(0.0, 89.0))
```

instead of importing the csv and see if your problem persists.